# ERROR while installing PyAudio in Rocky Linux 9

Tags: linux, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, package-management, pip

I just installed Rocky Linux 9 and my os contains "Development Tools" packages plus the required libraries for development and installing PyAudio such as portaudio and portaudio-devel, which is mentioned many times for other distros such as Ubuntu and RHEL.

By the way, I could not install PyAudio via mentioned ways on Rocky Linux 9. The error message during installation is that:

```
╰─ pip install pyaudio                                                                                                                                                                            ─╯
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
      copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
      running build_ext
      building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fstack-protector-strong -m64 -march=x86-64-v2 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/amirmasoud/.virtualenvs/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning-Spanish/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
      In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.c:1:
      src/pyaudio/device_api.h:7:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
          7 | #include "Python.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I searched around the problem and I am tackling it with that. Thereby, the following mentioned ways are among my efforts.

The one way I tried to fix that but not worked is that installing portaudio and portaudio-devel.
Another way was installing in the new Python virtualenv, however, it is clear that has not worked yet.
I also tried to install it by cloning its repository to utilize a different way of installing with pip. It has not worked either.

Comment: Have you tried these solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268630/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pyaudio-which-is-required-to-install-pyprojec)?

Comment: Yes, I have. It works on my Macbook, however, the problem is unsolved in Rocky Linux 9 on my Desktop which is the main device for my development.

Comment: You say you've researched around, but you do not say what you've tried to do to fix things and the outcome of those efforts. Can you please use the EDIT button and add missing information to your question to make it more clear and complete.

Comment: Try `sudo yum install python3-devel`. The key to solving your problem is to understand what the file `Python.h` is, what it is used for, and why it is missing from your system. When you see lines that start with `gcc`, that means that the package requires compilation and parts of the package are written in C or C++. `python-dev` contains the header files you need to build Python packages and extensions that are written in C or C++. This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) will help you learn more.